# Is there a simple way to test for a repeating condition in React functions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to increase the testing coverage of a React component I am developing. This component, however, has a `disabled` property, which basically stops all the component's functionallities.

However, this puts me in the annoying position of having to test the `disabled` condition for every single function in my code.

Below is the relevant testing coverage:

[image: Testing coverage of the relevant parts of my code]

Is there a way to test all of this at once using jest and/or react-testing library? Or is there a way for me to re-write my code so this isn't necessary?

I thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: If you are using HTML buttons, you can use their `disabled` attribute to delegate the `if` to the browser. If you are not, chances are that you should.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a loop to generate variations of tests.

```
describe("Component", () => {
  [false, true].map((disabled) => {
    it(`does a thing with disabled=${disabled}`, () => { ... });
  });
});
```

Alternately, annotate those lines with `/* istanbul ignore next */`:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
if(disabled) return;
```

Even better though, just get rid of the lines where you don't really need them – pretty sure you don't need to check for the disabled state in the event handlers, if they're not wired up to components in the first place...